# JPA when I should close entity manager

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

When I should close entity manager ?

```
public TYPE getItem(Long id) {
        if (id != null) {
            try {
                em = EMFactory.createEntityManager();
                TYPE item=em.find(entityClass, id);
                return item;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (em != null)
                    em.close();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

@WebListener
public class EMFactory implements ServletContextListener {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ejb");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
        emf.close();
    }

    public static EntityManager createEntityManager() {
        if (emf == null) {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("ejb");
          // throw new IllegalStateException("Context is not initialized yet.");
        }

        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

}
```

I close entity manager always after any operation create/update/select/remove. But I guess it is not efficiency. So how it should be implemented ?

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question I think the best approach is to use as the image I attached:
[image: entitymanager]

But you should probably take all the advantage that Java EE and EJB can give to you, you can have a container that manages all the hassle your going through. It handles the entitymanagerfactory in the background by the needs of your client session. 
Take a look at 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnblr.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [long-lived-transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-lived_transaction) on app start/stop, otherwise on session activation/passivation/creation.